# How to delete file that is created using Uri?

Tags: android

My app takes photo from camera and saves it in a file whose Uri is stored in SQL database. Initializing bitmap using Uri from database works flawlessly. However, when i try to initialize a file using Uri from database and then delete using `imagefile.delete()`it does not work. I have tried few methods given in other posts but none worked.

This i how i save file.

Intent for Camera:

```
Intent startCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (startCamera.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
                    {
                        photoFile= null;
                        try{
                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                        }
                        catch (IOException ex)
                        {
                            Log.e("File Creation","error");
                        }
                        if (photoFile!=null)
                        {
                            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"lcukerd.com.android.fileprovider",photoFile);
                            startCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
                            camerastarted=true;
                            startActivityForResult(startCamera,CAMERA_REQUEST);
                        }
                    }
```

Declared method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{
    String EName = "Stuff";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(EName,".jpg",storageDir);
    return image;
}
```

Compressing image:

```
photoFile.delete();
FileOutputStream out = null;
                    try {
                        File image = createImageFile();
                        photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "lcukerd.com.android.fileprovider", image);
                        out = new FileOutputStream(image);
                        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (out != null) {
                                out.close();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

saving Uri to database is simple conversion of Uri to string and then saving in TEXT column of table.

Help me delete image file .

Edit:

I tried following.

```
private void deleteimage(String imageloc)
    {
        File imagefile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(Uri.parse(imageloc)));
        Log.d("file deletion",String.valueOf(imagefile.delete())+" "+imageloc);
    }
    public String getRealPathFromURI( Uri contentUri) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and..

```
private void deleteimage(String imageloc)
    {
        File imagefile = new File(Uri.parse(imageloc).getpath());
        Log.d("file deletion",String.valueOf(imagefile.delete())+" "+imageloc);
    }
```

None worked.

Comment: `delete using imagefile.delete()it does not work.` doesn't tell us much.

Comment: check edit @Rotwang

Comment: Yes, but why do you get? A run-time error? Permissions? The file simply stays there? Or is it just still listed in the database because you forgot to remove the entry from the db table?

Comment: imagefile.delete(); returns false . nothing else shown .File is still there @Rotwang

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this is a `Uri` that you are getting from `FileProvider`, call `delete()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri` (plus `null` for the remaining parameters). That will delete the underlying file, at least according to [the `FileProvider` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#delete(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

Or, store the file path, rather than the `Uri`, in your database, since this is your file. You can recreate the `Uri` later as needed using `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`, and you can use `delete()` on `File` to delete the file, given its path.

Comment: I don't understand . What should i initialize FileProvider variable with? This doesn't work.   FileProvider imagefile =  new FileProvider();  
imagefile.delete(Uri.parse(imageloc),null,null);

Comment: @lcukerd: The first paragraph of my answer says to call `delete()` **on a `ContentResolver`**. You get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on some `Context` (e.g., an `Activity`).

Comment: Thanks again, it worked . I almost forgot about ContentResolver even though I used it in another activity :(